# jQuery: How can I loop over a set of elements finding only those matching the values within another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, return

I've basically got a little function called `findItem()` that is supposed to be finding the elements I'm looking for based on custom `data-` attributes on the element.

In this case these are purely numerical eg. `data-slide=1`.

I'm a bit clueless as to how to match the value of each item's data-slide to one that is contained within the other array.

Here is a more concrete example:

```
function findItem(count) {
    var collection = [];

    $.each(allMyLiItems, function(i, item) {

        if ( $(item).data('slide') == count ) { 
            collection.push(item);
        }

    });

    return $(collection);
}
findItem([1,3])
```

which does not work because `count` inside the if statement does not seem to match anything.

The page does contain 4 `<li data-slide="{number}">…` elements so 1,3 should return the first and third of those elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) and [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/):

```
function findItem(items) {
    return jQuery.grep($('li'), function(element, index) { 
       return jQuery.inArray($(element).data('slide'), items) != -1;
    });
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UVFBu/3/)

Comment: Hmm… i copy/pasted this into my file but logging out the result of `findItem([1,3])` returns the 3rd `li` 3 times instead of the 1st and 3rd `li` once, each. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jannis, Try my updated answer, I provided an example on jsFiddle as well.

Comment: I checked our the fiddle but as soon as you add more `li`s it breaks still, see my updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UVFBu/1/

Comment: @Jannis, I figured it out, see my updated answer and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UVFBu/3/

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue with the `count` inside the if statment not matching anything, try this:

```
function findItem(count) {
    var collection = [],
             count = count;

    $.each(allMyLiItems, function(i, item) {

        if ( $(item).data('slide') == count ) { 
            collection.push(item);
        }

    });

    return $(collection);
}
findItem([1,3])
```

This will create a closure so the anonymous function inside the `each` will be able to see it.

Your second issue is the fact that you're passing `count` as an array. So the `if` condition needs a little fixing:

```
function findItem(count) {
    var collection = [],
             count = count;

    $.each(allMyLiItems, function(i, item) {

        if ( count.indexOf($(item).data('slide')) !== -1 ) { 
            collection.push(item);
        }

    });

    return $(collection);
}
findItem([1,3])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still won't match since `count` inside the if statement is the whole array, not individual numbers being matched again. so count in the if statement is `[1,3,4]` which is not ` == 1` which is what the if statement would be asking for.

Comment: Sorry Jannis, you must have written your comment while I was updating it. The second half should fix your issue.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed. I applied your updated solution and that works great. Thanks a lot.